# Could someone explain this psoas stretch?

Tags: stretching

Without an image to accompany it, I don't really know how to perform this psoas stretch

> Stand up straight, and move one foot about 10 inches behind the other. Bend both your front and back knees, evenly distributing your weight between your two feet. Make sure your knees do not extend past your feet, and keep your hips reaching forward. Hold for 20 seconds, and switch feet

From:

How to Stretch the Psoas Muscle | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_2067121_stretch-psoas-muscle.html#ixzz1rbnJfSA8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psoas Stretch Options:

- **Standing** - Here is a video of a basic [standing psoas stretch](http://youtu.be/n3rFlQqbZVs?t=6s).  The description you gave of one foot 10" behind the other seems too narrow.
- **Kneeling** - Here is a [1/2 kneel position stretch of the psoas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=GVL74_zAaK4&feature=endscreen) that hits the important points of positioning of the thigh, pelvis, spine and arms.
- **Lying on Your Back** - With the basic psoas stretch lying on your back you pull one knee to your chest and the other thigh should easily touch the floor.  If this is too easy, you can advance this stretch by letting your thigh drop [off the edge of the bed or exercise mat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qcg4shTS0Sc) (Thomas test position).

Comment: Thx. That's what I needed. Makes much more sense now :)