# Core/Abdominal Exercises with Lordosis

Tags: abdominals, core

I have hyperlordosis as a result of very weak lower abs. I have been doing a lot of leg work on my hamstrings and glutes to strengthen my posterior chain, but I am having trouble finding any proper core/abdominal exercises to do strengthen my core that will not overly tax my psoas and thus exacerbate my issue. Does anyone have any thoughts? In addition, any stretches (I stretch my psoas and hip flexors 2x/day) would be very helpful. Thanks very much!

Comment: Also see [abdominal exercises](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/optimal-exercises-for-an-abdominal-workout) and [psoas stretch](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/could-someone-explain-this-psoas-stretch/6078#6078).

Comment: I would recommend you to look into Stuart McGill, and Chris Liebenson.

Comment: I suggest finding a physiotherapist who can design a rehab program for you. As said in the answers below, compound exercises, deadlifts strengthen everything in a balanced way. If I were you, I would correct any pre-existing problems with the help of a professional, before starting a new exercise program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the middle of dealing with my lordosis (also known as "anterior pelvic tilt" - you can find some good references if you search on that).

For exercises, dead bug variations and hip raises have been good. You need to be very good to make sure your back is flat during all of them. Oh, and the standing exercise where you have a band at your feet and step back and forth - that is a great glute exercise.

But for me, the big winners have been the deadlift and suitcase carry. You need to be very careful to start with light weight and to be very careful with your form, especially on deadlift.

I have also found that it's hard to tell the difference between exercises that aggravate my back and those that are just making the muscles tired. You will probably have to play around with things a bit.